Android Dual Screen POS - what’s the practical way
I purchased an Android dual-screen device, with one screen in portrait mode and the other in landscape mode.
The desired effect is for customers to use the portrait screen for self-service ordering while the staff can use the landscape screen’s POS system to place orders for other customers.

I tried running a different app on each screen: the portrait screen runs the self-service ordering app, and the landscape screen runs the POS app. However, the self-service order doesn’t get transmitted to the POS (this issue doesn’t occur when using two separate single-screen Android devices). I suspect it’s because both apps on the same device share the same IP, causing the API to not receive the order. I also tried using localhost but it didn’t work.

I attempted to use a single app to manage both screens by writing both the self-service ordering and POS functionalities into the same app, then using Display Manager to select the secondary display. I used DartEntryPoint to set the main() for the secondary screen, but the display on the secondary screen only shows after a manual refresh (hot reload) and setState doesn’t work.


I’ve been researching for a long time without any breakthrough and I’m not sure which direction is correct, so I’m looking for someone with relative experience in Android dual-screen POS to give me a practical approach.
